# Control property doesn't exist in a xamarin forms custom renderer

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I'm creating a Custom renderer on android and uwp.
Things go well on uwp. But when it comes to Android. The Control property doesn't get recognized 
it says: "The name 'Control' is not recognized in the current context".

This is the code i have written:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var gradientBoxView = Element as GradientBoxView;

            var linearGradient = gradientBoxView.Color;

            //colors
            var nativeColors = linearGradient.LinearGradientStops.Select(gs => gs.Color).ToArray();

            int[] colors = new int[nativeColors.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < nativeColors.Length; i++)
                colors[i] = nativeColors[i].ToAndroid();

            var gradient = new GradientDrawable(Utils.AndroidUtils.ToGradientDrawableFlow(linearGradient.Flow), colors);

            Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: what base type are you inheriting from?

Comment: Please post your full source code, so we can understand all the context.

Comment: @Jason I'm deriving from BoxRenderer based on Microsof docs

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro  Here is the source code [source code](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/2vutBEvA)